# Count associated rows from multiple tables using left join

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

There are three tables. **user**, **like**, **comment**. Table **like** and **comment** has rows associated to **user**. I need all users with their associated row count from table **like** and **comment**. It's easy to do when there is only one table associated. However, here is my query.

```
SELECT  u.id as id, u.display_name as displayName, 
        COUNT(x.user_id) as likeCount,
        COUNT(y.user_id) as commentCount
FROM `user` u
    LEFT JOIN
        `like` x ON x.user_id = u.id
    LEFT JOIN
        `comment` y ON y.user_id = u.id
GROUP BY u.id
```

Table relationships:
One user has many likes
One user has many comments

**commentCount** is giving correct rows count, but **likeCount** giving wrong rows count. **Please don't post answer which uses sub queries. I want it with only ONE SELECT clause. I am using MySQL. TIA**

Comment: hi, edited. hope it will be clear now.

Comment: And did you try using `DISTINCT `?

Comment: "Please don't post answers with subqueries" I don't see any other way of solving this. What's wrong with subqueries?

Comment: @Lamak I am not able to understand why should I used DISTINCT ? btw, let me try first answer.

Comment: It might be helpful to see some sample data from these tables, what results you expect, and what result you are getting.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the user count per individual table, like this:

```
SELECT user, COUNT(*) AS t1Count
FROM table1
GROUP BY user;

SELECT user, COUNT(*) AS t2Count
FROM table2
GROUP BY user;
```

Then you can join those two to the `Users` table to get the count of each. You should use `COALESCE()` to return null values with 0:

```
SELECT u.id, COALESCE(t1.t1Count, 0), COALESCE(t2.t2Count, 0)
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN(
   SELECT user, COUNT(*) AS t1Count
   FROM table1
   GROUP BY user) t1 ON u.id = t1.user
LEFT JOIN(
   SELECT user, COUNT(*) AS t2Count
   FROM table2
   GROUP BY user) t2 ON u.id = t2.user;
```

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b377c/3) example.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I had been searching for this answer. it works. Thanks again.

Comment: @mahbub.kuet glad I could help. If this is the solution you use, feel free to accept the answer so future readers will know how you solved the problem.

Comment: Hi. you there ? I have chosen your answer correct but just undo it because your solution uses sub queries too and I observed that it took around same time like pure sub query solution of this problem. I need solution without any sub queries. Would you tell me is it possible of not. I will accept your answer again after 12 hours if i will not get more solutions. Please be patient for next 12 hours.

Comment: @mahbub.kuet I do not think this is possible. Consider [this SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b377c/12). Looking at the joined rows side by side, there is no way to preform aggregation to know that user 1 appeared twice in table1 and once in table2. In this scenario, it looks as if they appeared twice in each table, which is not the case. It cannot be done with a single join.